# TinyMCE editor disable

Tags: tinymce, prototypejs

How can I disable tinyMCE?

I'm not trying to make tinyMCE not exist, just trying to disable the field temporarily using PrototypeJS's Form.disable.

Is there a particular way to mark a field disabled for editing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the plugin 'noneditable'

Or you could investigate the 'mode: exact' setting and only setting it on the exact id of the form field you want to control.

Your use case isn't really clear, so hope the above tips work.